# Input type= 'files', add value, which will be visible only for admin

Tags: html, forms, input

How to make that input type='file' will show the file that was added previously? So when admin open post page and want to make some changes he doesn't have to add file twice, i tried few things but input is always empty? It is possible to do it? That input will show file that was added previously? I mean the name of the file or path?

Comment: you would need a server side scripting language. But there would be far better ways of viewing previously uploaded content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that is even possible because of security  reasons.